# For loop Logistic regression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I want to built a for loop on a dataframe, with the goal to create a df with the Accuracy Score per stock.

The model for one stock works fine, but the for loop is not doing anything.Below is the output of the df, this is not the complete df.

```
Date        Close   ticker  rating  price   returns direction   long direction 
2021-02-06  21.8   AD.AS    1       21.8    -0.02   -1          1
2021-02-06  21.8   AD.AS    1       21.8    -0.02   -1          1
2021-02-06  21.8   APPL     1       153     -0.02   -1          1
2021-02-06  21.8   APPL     1       153     -0.02   -1          1

stock_df['ticker'].unique()
array(['CSCO', 'IBM', 'AMZN', 'AD.AS'], dtype=object)
```

We have finally figured out on how to do so, see below the code that we use now.

```
#for loop test
#Split data into training and test sets
stock_df = stock_df.dropna()

preds_sell = {}
y_test={}
temp = {}

# loop on every type
for ticker in stock_df['ticker'].unique():
    # slice
    stock_slice = stock_df[stock_df['ticker'] == ticker]

    X = stock_slice.drop(['long direction', 'BuyFlag','SellFlag', 'Date', 'ticker'], axis=1)
    y = stock_slice['SellFlag']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 5, shuffle=False)

    #Creatig duplicate for back testing
    X_test_2 = X_test

    #building logistic regression model on training data
    model1= LogisticRegression(random_state=0, multi_class='ovr', penalty='none', solver='newton-cg', class_weight={0:0.6, 1:0.4}).fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds_sell[ticker] = model1.predict(X_test)

    #Accuracy statistics
    print('Accuracy Score:', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, preds_sell[ticker]))  

    #Create classification report
    class_report=classification_report(y_test, preds_sell[ticker])
    print(class_report)

    # build dataframe with all your results
    temp[ticker] = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, preds_sell[ticker])

temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp, orient ='index').reset_index()
temp = final_df.rename(columns={'index': 'ticker', 0: 'Accuracy Score'})
final_df = final_df.append(temp)
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is not running because `stock['ticker'].unique()` is not having any value

Comment: post the full error.. I think the problem is with line `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 5, shuffle=False)`, it is expecting `x` and `y` to be of same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#for loop test
#Split data into training and test sets
stock_df = stock_df.dropna()

preds_sell = {}
y_test={}
temp = {}

# loop on every type
for ticker in stock_df['ticker'].unique():
    # slice
    stock_slice = stock_df[stock_df['ticker'] == ticker]

    X = stock_slice.drop(['long direction', 'BuyFlag','SellFlag', 'Date', 'ticker'], axis=1)
    y = stock_slice['SellFlag']

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 5, shuffle=False)

    #Creatig duplicate for back testing
    X_test_2 = X_test

    #building logistic regression model on training data
    model1= LogisticRegression(random_state=0, multi_class='ovr', penalty='none', solver='newton-cg', class_weight={0:0.6, 1:0.4}).fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds_sell[ticker] = model1.predict(X_test)

    #Accuracy statistics
    print('Accuracy Score:', metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, preds_sell[ticker]))  

    #Create classification report
    class_report=classification_report(y_test, preds_sell[ticker])
    print(class_report)

    # build dataframe with all your results
    temp[ticker] = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, preds_sell[ticker])

temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp, orient ='index').reset_index()
temp = final_df.rename(columns={'index': 'ticker', 0: 'Accuracy Score'})
final_df = final_df.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't update the variable value named `result` inside the for-loop.

Comment: that issue is fixed I think, but now I don't know what I am doing wrong.